# Prove that $\mathrm{Res}[f/g,z_0]=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$

Tags: complex-analysis

> I need to prove that if $f$ and $g$ are analytic in $D_r(z_0)$ and $g$ has a simple zero at $z_0$, then $$\mathrm{Res}[f/g,z_0]=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$

When $f(z_0)\neq 0$ and since $1/g$ has a simple pole at $z_0$ $$\mathrm{Res}[f/g,z_0]=\lim_{z\to z_0}(z-z_0)\frac{f(z)}{g(z)}=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$$
But what do I need to do when $f(z_0)=0$? Any help will be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When $f(z_0)=0$ the formula is trivially true because the singularity of $f/g$ is removable and the residue is zero.

Comment: How does it have a removable singularity ?

Comment: @Heisenberg, because $f(z)=0+f'(z_0)(z-z_0)+\cdots=(z-z_0)h(z)$.

Comment: when $f(z_0)=0$ it is identically zero or non zero in some punctured disk right. I am still not seeing this. sorry

Comment: @Heisenberg, both cases can happen and in both cases the singularity of $f/g$ is removable because $f(z)=(z−z_0)h(z)$ with $h$ analytic.

Comment: But $g(z_0)=0$ too right?

Comment: @Heisenberg, yes. But the *quotient* $f/g$ has limit.

Comment: your 1st comment assumes that $f$ has a simple zero but it does not have to be simple right?

Comment: @Heisenberg, $f(z_0)=0\implies f(z)=(z−z_0)h(z)$. Maybe $h$ has a (simple or multiple) zero. Maybe $h$ is identically zero. In any case, the only relevant fact is that $h$ is analytic.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for asking too many questions

Comment: @Heisenberg, don't worry.