# Compute $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2},i)$

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

> I have to compute $\mathrm{Res}(\frac{e^{iz}}{z(z^2+1)^2},i)$.

Do I have to use the result from [Prove that $\mathrm{Res}[f/g,z_0]=\frac{f(z_0)}{g'(z_0)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052755/resf-g-z-0-fracfz-0gz-0-proof?rq=1) (I think I have a pole of order $2$)? Otherwise, how could I do this?

I know that $\mathrm{Res}(f,z_0)+a_{-1}= \int_{C_p} \frac{f(z)dz}{z-z_0}$, where $C_p$ is simply the circle at $z_0$ with radius of convergence $p$ ($0<p<r$) in positive direction.

Comment: Do you know that there is a general formula for computing the residue at a point $z_0$ with a pole of order $n$? It is: $$\frac{1}{(n-1)!}\lim_{z \to z_0} \left[ \frac{d^{n-1}}{dz^{n-1}} (z-z_0)^nf(z) \right] $$

Comment: Precisely because your pole isn't simple, as required in the link you give, that won't work here... You can try either wgrenard's suggestion or take a peek to my answer. Whatever makes it simpler for you. By the way, what you say "I know that" looks odd: what is that $\;a_{-1}\;$? Looks like the coefficient in some Laurent series...

Answer (score 2):

You can try to develop the Laurent series (only some very few siginificative terms) around $\;i\;$ :

$$\frac{e^{iz}}{z(1+z^2)^2}=e^{-1}e^{i(z-i)}\cdot\frac1i\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{z-i}i}\cdot\frac1{(z-i)^2}\cdot\left(-\frac14\right)\cdot\frac1{\left(1+\frac{z-i}{2i}\right)^2}=$$

$$=\frac i{4e}\left(1+\color{red}{i(z-i)}+\ldots\right)\left(1-\color{red}{\frac{z-i}i}-(z-i)^2+\ldots\right)\color{red}{\frac1{(z-i)^2}}\left(1-\color{red}{\frac{z-i}{i}}-\ldots\right)^2=$$

Now pay attention to the red terms  (By the way, the above shows clearly the pole is a double one):

$$=\frac i{4e}\cdot\frac1{(z-i)^2}\left(1+2i(z-i)+\ldots\right)\left(1-\color{red}{\frac{z-i}{i}}-\ldots\right)=$$

$$=\frac i{4e}\cdot\frac1{(z-i)^2}\left(1+3i(z-i)+\ldots\right)=...-\frac3{4e}(z-i)^{-1}+\ldots$$

and thus the residue is $\;-\frac3{4e}\;$